# Azure REST API получение токена без браузера

Tags: sql-server, oauth, azure

У меня есть веб-сервис (ASP Core 3.1), которому нужна авторизация для доступа к Azure REST API (ресурс https://management.azure.com, провайдер Microsoft.Sql). Стандартная oAuth авторизация не подходит, т.к. сервис работает самостоятельно и нет пользователя, который будет авторизовываться через браузер.

Я так же пыталась получить токен другим способом. Токен возвращается, но запросы с его использованием возвращают ошибку 403 (Forbidden). Метод получения токена:

```
   private static async Task<string> GetToken()
    {
        var url =
            "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/token";

        var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "grant_type", "client_credentials" },
            { "client_id", {clientId} },
            { "client_secret", {clientSecret} },
            { "resource", "https://management.azure.com/" }
        };

        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(dict);

        using var client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
        var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
        var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        return result;
        }
    }
```

Для получения токена в разделе App registrations на портале Azure зарегестрировано приложение с такими разрешениями:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ClientId, ClientSecret и т.п. берутся в обоих случаях у него.
Почему токен с теми же авторизационными данными, но полученный через браузер, имеет доступы, а токен, полученный вторым способом, нет? 
Возможно, есть какие-то более адекватные способы получения токена без участия пользователя?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Второй способ все-таки работает. Для этого на портале нужно зайти в Subscription, в разделе Access Control (IAM) добавить зарегестрированное в App registrations приложение как пользователя и назначить ему нужную роль/создать кастомную роль с нужными разрешениями.